# Linear homogeneous ODE with time dependent matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering, if $x'(t)=A(t)x(t)$ where $A(t)$ is a continuos $n\times n$ matrix, how do I show that it has $n$ linearly independent solutions?

Comment: Is $\displaystyle{\large A\left(t\right)A\left(t'\right)=A\left(t'\right)A\left(t\right)\,,\quad\forall t, t'}$ ?.

Answer (score -4):

Think of $x(t)$ and $A(t)$ as 1-dimensional real functions, then it's a standtard ODE whose solution is $$x(t)=c e^{\int A(t)dt}$$

where $c\in \mathbb R$. This is actually the solution for your case as well, but now $c \in \mathbb R^n$ and all that remains is to know how to compute $e^{\int A(t)dt}$. I bet you already guess how to compute $\int A(t)dt$, all that remains then is to find out how to compute $e^M$ being $M$ a matrix. That is called the matrix exponential, and you can find how to compute it in Wikipedia. In fact, you can compute $f(M)$ for any function $f$

Also, since $A(t)$ is continous, the matrix $\int A(t)dt$ will always exist, and the following relation for the determinant of the matrix $e^{\int A(t)dt}$ will hold $det(e^{\int A(t)dt})=e^{tr(\int A(t)dt)}$ by Jacobi's formula. So you can already compute how the determinant of $e^{\int A(t)dt}$ will vary with time without actually computing the matrix, and as you can see, it will never be $0$, which tells you that the equation will have $n$ independent solutions.

Comment: That solution is valid whenever $A(t)A(t') = A(t')A(t)\,,\quad\forall t,t'$.

Comment: interesting, could you provide a link explaining the reason? @Felix Marin

Comment: @FelixMarin, thats not required since if M is time dependent then computing $e^M$ will require the computation of the time ordered exponential which is not expected to be commutative with respect to multiplication

Comment: @frogeyedpeas That was what I was thinking about. It is common in Quantum Mechanics. Thanks.